# h2o XGBoost no backend found

Tags: python, h2o, xgboost

I am running h2o automl in python on a windows machine. I noticed that none of the models which were being built were based on XGBoost.

I tried running the following code:

```
 import h2o
 from h2o.automl import H2OAutoML
 h2o.init()

 h2o.estimators.xgboost.H2OXGBoostEstimator.available()
```

I get the notification below:

```
Cannot build an XGBoost model - no backend found.
```

I know with other ML packages (Keras for example) you can set the config file to specify back ends or you can set the back end as an environment variable. Is there a way to do this for h20?

FYI I am running h2o v3.22.1.6

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your error... Have you tried to reinstall `h2o`?

Comment: xgboost needs to be compiled with a compiler, unlike java code.  So unless you have linux x86_64 it won’t work inside of h2o-3.

Comment: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html#limitations says it is not available for Windows. Is this actual info? I have the same problem with R running on Windows.